# Getter and setter for input HTML

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a problem where I need to put numbers in input fields in German format. For Example, if the number is `10.5` then in German format it would be like this `10,5`. It means that the `.` will be replaced with `,`. My problem is that I need to do calculations on the numbers which means that I need to convert decimal numbers to German format and then after finishing the calculations, need to convert that value to German format again. All of this is needed to be done manually each time which is quite annoying. So, my question is that is there any way we can set a `getter` and a `setter` value for HTML inputs. I want if the value is added to the input field by any means either from `jQuery` change function or by entered by the user manually, it converts a decimal number i.e `10.5` the German format `10,5` and likewise, when we need to get the value of that particular input field it automatically converts the German value i.e `10,5` to a decimal number `10.5`. Is there any solution for this problem? I have researched throughout the internet and couldn't get the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a function that returns a value getter that implements the desired functionality, a setter with the same, and the underlying element:

```js
const makeInputWrapper = (selector) => {
  const input = document.querySelector(selector);
  const get = () => Number(input.value.replaceAll(',', '.'));
  const set = (newVal) => {
    const formatted = String(newVal).replace('.', ',');
    input.value = formatted;
  };
  return { input, get, set };
};

const wrapper = makeInputWrapper('.foo');
const val = wrapper.get();
console.log('orig val was', val);
wrapper.set(12.56)
```

```html
<input class="foo" value="4,1">
```

Comment: Thank you :). That's good. But is there any solution that I don't need to call `wrapper.get();` functions each time? And one more question is that why do I need to put `const` time before the variables?

Comment: You'll need to property lookup or a function call regardless in order to access the current value in the input. If not `wrapper.get()`, then `input.value`, even if no text transformation had to take place at all. Why use `const`? Because it makes code more readable and maintainable when one can see that a particular identifier absolutely will not be reassigned. You should be using `const` 95% of the time for variable declarations; never use `var`, and only use `let` when you have to reassign.